# Explanation of Dynamic Programming "Guess and Verify" Technique

Tags: dynamic-programming, bellman-equations

According to my textbook, the analytical technique for solving a Bellman's Equation is as follows:

1. Guess a form for $V_0(x)$
2. Solve the maximization problem with respect to the control and obtain a policy function $x' = h_0(x)$
3. Update the guess by plugging the policy function such that $V_1(x) =F(x,h_0(x)) + \beta V_0(h_0(x))$
4. Repeat the above until $V_{i+1} = V_i$ At this point, the equation is solved.

My question is, why does this technique, specifically the step, $V_{i+1}= V_i$, solve the Bellman equation? 
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not putting this in an answer because it's too vague but there is probably a proof, that if a function has certain properties ( like the one in 3) and you obtain the fixed point of the solution of that function, then that point is a  maximum. But that's a guess. I would google for "fixed point Bellman" and see what comes up.

Comment: At a rough glance, it looks the answer is in the paper at the link below  It might be  related to what I said but I would read it carefully as I plan to some day.  https://web.stanford.edu/~pkurlat/teaching/5%20-%20The%20Bellman%20Equation.pdf